# Schwäbisch, Badisch: „Schenossewasser“ o.ä. in der Bedeutung von „Peanuts“?

Tags: single-word-request, dialect, swabian, alemannic

Gibt es im Schwäbischen oder Badischen ein Wort, das so ähnlich klingt wie *Schnosselwasser, Schenossewasser* und bedeutet: ein zu vernachlässigender Geldbetrag *(Peanuts)?*

Beispiel:

> Das ist doch …wasser für die.
>    (Das zahlen die doch aus der Portokasse.)

Ich stolperte gerade darüber in einer mundartlichen Transkription.

Comment: Es gibt die *spanischen Nüsse*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### [Nasenwasser](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=%7E%7Enur%20ein%20Nasenwasser%20sein&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)

Offenbar ist es hier zu einer Verschmelzung in der mundartlichen Aussprache gekommen. Die Aussage dürfte also wie folgt lauten:

> Des i**sch en Nôse(n)wasser** für die

Weitere Referenzen: [myDict](http://www.mydict.com/Wort/Nasenwasser/), [Schwäbische Zeitung](http://www.schwaebische.de/region/oberschwaben/bad-waldsee/stadtnachrichten-bad-waldsee_artikel,-150-Euro-Betreuungsgeld-sind-ein-reines-Nasenwasser-_arid,5255890.html), [von Schmid: Schwäbisches Wörterbuch](http://books.google.de/books?id=YYASAAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA402&ots=X1UStPDRV7&dq=nasenwasser%20herkunft&pg=PA402#v=onepage&q=nasenwasser%20herkunft&f=false)

Leider konnte ich nichts zur Etymologie finden.

Comment: Vielleicht auch `des isch eh schee Nasewasser` (ein _schönes_ Nasenwasser, schön hier als ein Asudruck der Steigerung)